# Gremlin MergeV To Update an Existing Element's property and Single Cardinality

Tags: go, gremlin, upsert, amazon-neptune

I am using Amazon Neptune with Gremlin-go for our Graph Database needs. I am working on code to insert/update (upsert) an element with `g.mergeV()`. However, when a match is found, and a property gets updated, the new value is added to a value-list. I wanted to set the property that is getting updated as a `single` (Cardinality), so at any given time it will have only one value. This is my code

```java
g.mergeV(['firstname': 'fname']).
    option(onCreate, [(T.label): 'Someone','lastname': 'lname']).
    option(onMatch, ['lastname': 'lname1']))
```

I would like the values on update to look like this

```java
{'firstname': ['fname'], 'lastname': ['lname1']}
```

But, values after update look like this

```java
{'firstname': ['fname'], 'lastname': ['lname','lname1']}
```

Unfortunately, Neptune's default property Cardinality is a List. I was hoping using the `property()` would work if a match is found, however get this error

```java
g.mergeV(['firstname': 'fname']).
    option(onCreate, [(T.label): 'Someone','lastname': 'lname']).
    option(onMatch, __.property(single, ['lastname': 'lname1'])))

"detailedMessage": "com.amazon.neptune.tinkerpop.structure.NeptuneVertex cannot be cast to java.util.Map"
```

I have also tried the fold/coalesce/unfold route, but values don't get updated if a record is found

```java
g.V().hasLabel("Someone").
      has("firstname", "fname").
      has("lastname", "lname").
      fold().
      coalesce(unfold(), 
               __.addV("Someone").property(single, ["firstname": "fname", "lastname": "lname1"]))
```

I am open to using another way, as long as it is upsert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments.

1. The default Cardinality used by Amazon Neptune is actually Set and not List
2. To use the `coalesce` form of the query, you need to provide an action more than just `unfold` for the LHS as that will be the path taken if the vertex already exists. So the query will be something like this:

```java
g.V().hasLabel("Someone").
      has("firstname", "fname").
      has("lastname", "lname").
      fold().
      coalesce(unfold().property(single,"firstname","Newname"), 
               addV("Someone").property(single, ["firstname": "fname", "lastname": "lname1"]))
```

3. The `mergeV` query can be made to work. You just need to use a slightly different form along these lines. The `sideEffect` performs the actual update and the `constant([:])` generates an empty map as there are no more changes needed.

```java
g.mergeV(["firstname":"firstname"]).
   option(Merge.onMatch,sideEffect(property(single,"firstname","Newname")).constant([:]))
```

**Note** You will need to be running Amazon Neptune with an engine version of 1.2.1.0.R2 or higher for the `sideEffect` version of the query to work.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have tried both of your suggestions and they work. I have marked your response as the accepted answer.