# Batch mergeV working well when creating items, but yielding unexpected results when updating

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

I used this thread [Gremlin MergeV To Update an Existing Element's property and Single Cardinality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76203885/gremlin-mergev-to-update-an-existing-elements-property-and-single-cardinality) as a reference to test a mergeV query that creates a vertex with some properties if its id is not found or just updates them if the id is found. Strangely enough, if I delete all vertices to start fresh, it successfully creates all 3 vertices with the correct properties. However, whenever I try to run the same query again with different property values, the output becomes really unexpected, like properties from one item going to the other. Wonder what's going wrong.

```
g.mergeV([(T.id):'v-1']).
    option(onCreate, [(T.label): 'Person', 'email': 'person-1@example.org', 'age': {age}]).option(onMatch, sideEffect(property(single, 'email', 'person-1@example.org')).sideEffect(property(single, 'age', {age})).constant([:])).
  mergeV([(T.id):'v-2']).
    option(onCreate, [(T.label): 'Person', 'email': 'person-2@example.org', 'age': {age}]).option(onMatch, sideEffect(property(single, 'email', 'person-2@example.org')).sideEffect(property(single, 'age', {age})).constant([:])).
  mergeV([(T.id):'v-3']).
    option(onCreate, [(T.label): 'Person', 'email': 'person-3@example.org', 'age': {age}]).option(onMatch, sideEffect(property(single, 'email', 'person-3@example.org')).sideEffect(property(single, 'age', {age})).constant([:])).
    id()
```

If, for example, I change replace 'person-2@example.org' by 'person-22@example.org' in both occurences of v-2, I get an output like this:

```
{
  "requestId": "7fd4de9f-8c25-4493-98f7-a39c0292edc5",
  "status": {
    "message": "",
    "code": 200,
    "attributes": {
      "@type": "g:Map",
      "@value": []
    }
  },
  "result": {
    "data": {
      "@type": "g:List",
      "@value": [
        {
          "@type": "g:Vertex",
          "@value": {
            "id": "v-1",
            "label": "Person",
            "properties": {
              "age": [
                {
                  "@type": "g:VertexProperty",
                  "@value": {
                    "id": {
                      "@type": "g:Int32",
                      "@value": 92892634
                    },
                    "value": {
                      "@type": "g:Int32",
                      "@value": 30
                    },
                    "label": "age"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "email": [
                {
                  "@type": "g:VertexProperty",
                  "@value": {
                    "id": {
                      "@type": "g:Int32",
                      "@value": -928922435
                    },
                    "value": "person-22@example.org",
                    "label": "email"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "@type": "g:Vertex",
          "@value": {
            "id": "v-2",
            "label": "Person",
            "properties": {
              "age": [
                {
                  "@type": "g:VertexProperty",
                  "@value": {
                    "id": {
                      "@type": "g:Int32",
                      "@value": 92892635
                    },
                    "value": {
                      "@type": "g:Int32",
                      "@value": 30
                    },
                    "label": "age"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "email": [
                {
                  "@type": "g:VertexProperty",
                  "@value": {
                    "id": {
                      "@type": "g:Int32",
                      "@value": -1319118437
                    },
                    "value": "person-3@example.org",
                    "label": "email"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "@type": "g:Vertex",
          "@value": {
            "id": "v-3",
            "label": "Person",
            "properties": {
              "age": [
                {
                  "@type": "g:VertexProperty",
                  "@value": {
                    "id": {
                      "@type": "g:Int32",
                      "@value": 92892636
                    },
                    "value": {
                      "@type": "g:Int32",
                      "@value": 30
                    },
                    "label": "age"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "email": [
                {
                  "@type": "g:VertexProperty",
                  "@value": {
                    "id": {
                      "@type": "g:Int32",
                      "@value": -1319118436
                    },
                    "value": "person-3@example.org",
                    "label": "email"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "meta": {
      "@type": "g:Map",
      "@value": []
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce this. Could you please provide each value you are using for `age` ?  I would like to test with the exact values you are using. Also, which system was the above test run on? The tag says Neptune was used but those IDs lead me to believe it may have been a different database.

Comment: For now I used 12,13,14 for the initial ages and 22,23,24 for the second set. I do see some odd behavior which needs further investigation. It also seems to happen on TinkerGraph.

Comment: A couple of notes: 1/ This is failing the same way using TinkerGraph and Neptune so is likely an issue in the Apache TinkerPop code. It needs more investigation and then most likely a Jira. 2/ A new syntax has been introduced into TinkerPop as part of the 3.7.0 release to make working with cardinality in maps easier. Please refer to [this documentation](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/upgrade/#_map_and_cardinality). As soon as Neptune moves up to the 3.7 level that syntax will be supported.

Comment: I have created a Jira against Apache TinkerPop Gremlin to aid further debugging this issue. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-3036

Comment: I'm indeed using AWS Neptune. Thanks for addressing the issue with the ticket. Any suggestions on what is the most straightforward of pushing a vertex on Neptune with a set of properties using the following logic:
1) create it with the properties if there is no such id
2) update it with the properties if there is an id match

Comment: To give a bit of context, I'm currently working with a db that has hundreds of millions of vertices and I need to update/populate fields with calculated data (sentiment analysis, cluster labels etc..). I'm currently performing those updates via queries inside the scripts that execute each step of the pipeline. In this scenario, it would not be very practical to first retrieve all existing ids with a query (it is costly) to know beforehand which vertexes are missing certain fields in order to avoid errors like 'vertex id already exists'.

Comment: You'd likely need to fallback to using the `fold().coalesce()` method that we relied on before the existence of `mergeV/E`.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/gremlin-efficient-upserts-pre-3.6.html